# Interactive draggable chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, interactive

I am looking to create an iterative chart for people to drag a circle to a section of a chart and then submit it. This circle would then show up on the chart for others to see. The idea behind this is to determine what is the most important aspect of a project is to the stakeholders.

I have a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7n96q2n/)** showing part of this functionality. What I want to 'record' is the position of the circle when they are done moving it and then put that somewhere (CSV) upon submit. Then I want to have all of the circles from the CSV show on the chart.

Inspecting the element (circle) will show its position.

Does this make sense? Anyone have any ideas? Is there a better way to do this?

Sample Code cobbled together from various online tutorials:

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     version="1.1"
     width="970"
     height="450">

    <script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
    var selectedElement = 0;
    var currentX = 0;
    var currentY = 0;
    var currentMatrix = 0;

    function selectElement(evt) {
      selectedElement = evt.target;
      currentX = evt.clientX;
      currentY = evt.clientY;
      currentMatrix = selectedElement.getAttributeNS(null, "transform").slice(7,-1).split(' ');

      for(var i=0; i<currentMatrix.length; i++) {
        currentMatrix[i] = parseFloat(currentMatrix[i]);
      }

      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove", "moveElement(evt)");
      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout", "deselectElement(evt)");
      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseup", "deselectElement(evt)");
    }

    function moveElement(evt) {
      var dx = evt.clientX - currentX;
      var dy = evt.clientY - currentY;
      currentMatrix[4] += dx;
      currentMatrix[5] += dy;

      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "matrix(" + currentMatrix.join(' ') + ")");
      currentX = evt.clientX;
      currentY = evt.clientY;
    }

    function deselectElement(evt) {
      if(selectedElement != 0){
          selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove");
          selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout");
          selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmouseup");
          selectedElement = 0;
          }
        }

    ]]> </script>

    <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="970" height="399" fill="#ecf0f1" stroke="black"/>
    <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="970" height="299" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
    <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="970" height="199" fill="#ecf0f1" stroke="black"/>
    <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="970" height="99" fill="none" stroke="black"/>




    <circle
        id ="circleitem"
        cx="50" 
        cy="50" 
        r="20" 
        stroke="black" 
        stroke-width="2" 
        fill="#c0392b" 
        transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)"
        onmousedown="selectElement(evt)"/>


</svg>

<input name="position1" class="inputfield" id="position1" readonly="readonly">
<input name="position2" class="inputfield" id="position2" readonly="readonly">



<script type="text/javascript">

position1.value = currentMatrix[4];
position2.value = currentMatrix[5];  


</script>
```

Thanks so much

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Should be in comments but it's a long one: Try a real time architecture with Node server:

Along with `socket.io` (check the real time chat coding, use that as a base).

On `deselectElement()`, POST `ID,x,y` (where `ID=random_sessionID, x=currentMatrix[4], y=currentMatrix[5]`) to server. Tweak the chat server to record this to an associative array, eg `users[ID] = [x,y];` and "broadcast" the data to all connected clients.

A) New clients connecting to the server will receive a JSON version of the `users` array.

B) Connected client will receive updates of `ID,x,y` and the two scenarios are:

1. If existing ID, update the x,y values.
2. If new ID, create new circle with `id=ID` on x,y position.

Note: You can use other backend server, just that implementing real time update with websocket is simplified on Node server.